# Unir 2 graficas en c# con diferente escala

Tags: c#, .net

Saludos a todos, ¿alguien me puede ayudar con esta duda por favor?. Tengo una aplicación desarrollada en C# que me muestra en pantalla graficas de barras. Necesito trabajarlas y unirlas mediante escalas diferentes, solo he trabajado con una escala, por lo tanto no sé como hacerla y también no sé si se pueda. Tengo que comentarles que he visto ejemplos en Excel, pero no he tenido experiencia para hacerla en c#.

Este ejemplo que les muestro, es a donde me gustaría llegar. Es decir 2 graficas unidas, pero con diferente escala. Gracias por su apoyo

```
<asp:Chart ID="graf_calificacion_servicio_mensual" runat="server" Height="396px" Width="760px">
            <Series>
                <asp:Series Name="Series1" CustomProperties="DrawingStyle=Cylinder">
                </asp:Series>
            </Series>
            <ChartAreas>
                <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1">
                    <AxisY IsLabelAutoFit="False" TextOrientation ="Auto"
                            TitleFont="Verdana, 10pt" Interval="Auto">
                            <LabelStyle Font="Microsoft Sans Serif" />
                    </AxisY>

                    <AxisX IsLabelAutoFit="false" LabelAutoFitMaxFontSize="10" 
                            LabelAutoFitMinFontSize="8" LabelAutoFitStyle="None" Interval="1">
                            <LabelStyle Angle ="90" Font="Microsoft Sans Serif" IsEndLabelVisible ="false" />

                    </AxisX>
                </asp:ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
        </asp:Chart>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: y como es que dibuja las graficas?

Comment: @gbianchi que buena pregunta jajaja.

Comment: Las graficas están construidas en C# Chart, cada una tiene diferente escala. Me gustaría que una estuviera al frente y otra atrás, es el ejemplo que les muestro en la pantalla

Comment: Hace falta el código con el que las creas, y que especifique si es WPF o WinForms.

Comment: con el control chart? a eso te referis? vamos a necesitar ver el codigo de como ploteas cada dimension y que pasa cuando mandas las dos dimensiones juntas.

Comment: Se anexa el código

Comment: ok.. no es c#, o si lo es es asp.net con c# atras.. pero el atras no lo sabemos. y por otro lado hay un tag series, no deberias poner las dos series que queres ahi.. y ver como se renderiza.. y leer las propiedades de renderizado del control?

Comment: Les comentaba desde el inicio que es c#, las series se pueden agregar, pero no sé donde se habilitan las propiedades y agregar las 2 graficas.